# How to start Selenium in a Jenkins job

Tags: ant, selenium, jenkins, selenium-rc, jenkins-plugins

I am using Jenkins and Ant to execute my Selenium tests. I would like to make a job that would do the following:

- starts Selenium server
- executes tests and
- kills Selenium server after all tests are run.

I am able to start the Selenium server manually with the following command:

```
java -jar selenium-2.16.1\selenium-server-standalone-2.25.jar
```

But I cannot find a Jenkins plugin that would do the start/stop for me. All I can find are some Selenium reporting plugins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if there is a plugin, but you can just run the launch and kill commands via the Jenkins job.
Under Build, if you add an `Execute shell` build step, you can run your commands from there.

*Note* - The path to the selenium server is relative to the current work directory.

Comment: My errors:

[test] $ sh -xe C:\Windows\TEMP\hudson3149349550017990432.sh
The system cannot find the file specified
FATAL: command execution failed
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "sh" (in directory "C:\Program Files\Jenkins\workspace\test"): CreateProcess error=2, 
Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
 at java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
 at java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(Unknown Source)
 ... 17 more
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE

Comment: Can you please provide an example for starting and killing command for selenium server through jenkins job?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your error trace, looks like you are running this on a windows PC. you need to be running this as a "execute windows batch command" then run 
java -jar selenium-2.16.1\selenium-server-standalone-2.25.jar  
 Assuming that you have your jar file on the workspace. or you beed to point it at the right path